# Angular CLI showing the wrong time

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run an Angular command the time returned is 1 hour behind. I believe this is causing problems in terms of detecting change with livereload. How do I find what the problem is to this?

Output:

```
[ng] Date: 2020-03-11T08:08:14.687Z
```

Expected output:

```
[ng] Date: 2020-03-11T09:08:14.687Z
```

If I type the command `time` in the CLI it displays the right time to me. It seems to be Angular CLI related.

For the sake of clarity, this is the output I get when I run `ng build`.

[image]

This time is not correct it is 1 hour behind of my timezone.

Comment: share some code Sinan.

Comment: What code? I use this in combination with Ionic. The problem occurs when I type `ionic serve` in the output of the cli. There is nothing related to code.

Comment: Maybe one of those commands prints UTC time?...

Comment: It is showing UTC. You are possibly viewing it from CET zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date displayed is in UTC. Please notice the `Z` as the last character of the timestamp. I guess it is used on purpose.

Please take a look at this issue: [ng serve doesn't consider the timezone when printing the output](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12562) 
and try to make the replacements as mentioned.

Comment: Ah thanks. This explains it and it should not be related to the problem then.For anyone looking to override this problem: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12562#issuecomment-449583971